Animating Merge Sort in Blender with Python Script for Educational Visuals
Body:
I'm trying to create an animation in Blender that visually demonstrates the merge sort algorithm. The animation involves colored bars representing array elements, which move to show the sorting process. I want the bars to animate moving up during the merge phase and return to their original position after merging.
Current Script:


import bpy
import random
Function to change the color of an object
def change_object_color(obj, color):
if not obj.data.materials:
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")
obj.data.materials.append(mat)
else:
mat = obj.data.materials[0]
mat.use_nodes = True
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
principled_bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
if principled_bsdf:
    principled_bsdf.inputs["Base Color"].default_value = color

Function to get the height of an object (used for bar comparison)
def get_height(obj):
original_height = 1
return obj.scale.z * original_height
Function to create bars representing array elements
def create_bars(num_elements=20, bar_width=0.5, max_height=5, data=None):
if data is None:
data = [random.randint(1, max_height) for _ in range(num_elements)]
else:
num_elements = len(data)
bars = []
for i, value in enumerate(data):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, location=(i * bar_width * 2, 0, 0))
    bar = bpy.context.object
    bar.scale.x = bar_width
    bar.scale.z = value
    bar.location.z = value / 2  # Position bars on the ground
    change_object_color(bar, (random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1))
    bars.append(bar)

return bars

Function to move bars up or down by a given offset
def move_bars(bars, delta_y):
for bar in bars:
bar.location.y += delta_y
Function to insert keyframes for bar location
def update_location(bar, frame_num):
bar.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=frame_num)
Function to insert keyframes for all bars in a given list
def update_location_all(bars, frame_num):
for bar in bars:
update_location(bar, frame_num)
Function to get the x-coordinates of all bars in a given list
def get_coordinates(objects):
return [(obj.location.x, obj.location.y, obj.location.z) for obj in objects]
Recursive function to animate the merge sort process
def merge_sort_animation(arr, start, end, sort_speed):
global frame_num
if end - start > 1:
mid = (start + end) // 2
# Move only the current sublist bars up
bars = arr[start:end]
move_bars(bars, 5)
update_location_all(bars, frame_num)
frame_num += sort_speed
    # Recursively sort left and right halves
    merge_sort_animation(arr, start, mid, sort_speed)
    merge_sort_animation(arr, mid, end, sort_speed)

    # Merge the sorted halves
    merge_animation(arr, start, mid, end)

    # Move the merged bars back down
    move_bars(arr[start:end], -5)
    update_location_all(arr[start:end], frame_num)
    frame_num += sort_speed

Function to animate the merging process
def merge_animation(arr, start, mid, end):
global sort_speed
global frame_num
left = arr[start:mid]
right = arr[mid:end]
i = j = 0
sorted_bars = []
# Get x-coordinates for the bars in this range
coordinates = [bar.location.x for bar in arr[start:end]]
while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
    if left[i].scale.z <= right[j].scale.z:
        sorted_bars.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        sorted_bars.append(right[j])
        j += 1

# Add any remaining bars
sorted_bars.extend(left[i:])
sorted_bars.extend(right[j:])

# Update positions and keyframes
for idx, bar in enumerate(sorted_bars):
    bar.location.x = coordinates[idx]
    update_location(bar, frame_num)

# Update the original array with sorted bars
arr[start:end] = sorted_bars
frame_num += sort_speed

Example usage
num_elements = 16           # Number of elements to sort
bar_width = 0.5             # Width of each bar
max_height = 20             # Max height for bars
sort_speed = 10             # Frames per action
frame_num = 1               # Start frame for the animation
Clear existing objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
Create bars and start the animation
bars = create_bars(num_elements, bar_width, max_height)
update_location_all(bars, frame_num)
frame_num += sort_speed
merge_sort_animation(bars, 0, len(bars), sort_speed)


Explanation:

change_object_color: Changes the material color of a bar.
create_bars: Generates bars with randomized heights and colors.
merge_sort_animation: Recursively animates the merge sort process.
merge_animation: Handles the merging and updates the bar positions and keyframes.

Question: I'm looking for ways to optimize this script or suggestions for best practices when creating animated visualizations in Blender with Python. Are there more efficient techniques for updating keyframes or managing animations in Blender for educational content?
Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Hello and welcome. What is your question? You just dumped a lot of code, but did not formulate an inquiry or expose an issue. Could you edit your post and describe what the issue is, along with formulating an actual question we can answer?

I have put an organized code; the problem is when I run it the bars aren't ordered increaingly it's more like randomly

Could you edit your post and add those details directly into your question?

Hello, I thank you for providing an answer to your question and it seems to be a perfectly valid answer, although I wouldn't have the slightest idea since I don't know what the question is. I honestly fail to see how this would help anybody else in the future, usually code in a question is there to accompany the actual body of the question, readable in human language and parsed by the search engines to be able to find it in the future. Just my 2 cents, I don't mean to be aggravating, I just want the time you spent on writing this to benefit others. Cheers

merge sort is one of the algorithms that are teached at uni and I wanted to animated but because I amkind of new to blnder but I am quite good with python and math I am using the python module to animate it. the advantages: the scripts can be used by any and so for the animation and modifiable(the advanteges of having a code) and for me the full control of what's happening and learning how blender works

The problem was in updating the coordinates changing the coordinates of the sublists didn't change of the upper list (it didn't change the order) so at merge_animation I had to create a list representing the sorted then update the old list with this one. I switched to using arrays.
import bpy
import random

def change_object_color(obj, color):
    if not obj.data.materials:
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")
        obj.data.materials.append(mat)
    else:
        mat = obj.data.materials[0]

    mat.use_nodes = True
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    principled_bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
    if principled_bsdf:
        principled_bsdf.inputs["Base Color"].default_value = color

def get_height(obj):
    original_height = 1
    return obj.scale.z * original_height

def create_bars(num_elements=20, bar_width=0.5, max_height=5, data=None):
    if data is None:
        data = [random.randint(1, max_height) for _ in range(num_elements)]
    else:
        num_elements = len(data)

    bars = []
    for i, value in enumerate(data):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, location=(i * bar_width * 2, 0, 0))
        bar = bpy.context.object
        bar.scale.x = bar_width
        bar.scale.z = value
        bar.location.z = value / 2  # Position bars on the ground
        change_object_color(bar, (random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1))
        bars.append(bar)

    return bars

def move_bars(bars, delta_y):
    for bar in bars:
        bar.location.y += delta_y

def update_location(bar, frame_num):
    bar.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=frame_num)

def update_location_all(bars, frame_num):
    for bar in bars:
        update_location(bar, frame_num)

def get_coordinates(objects):
    return [(obj.location.x, obj.location.y, obj.location.z) for obj in objects]

def merge_sort_animation(arr, start, end, sort_speed):
    global frame_num
    if end - start > 1:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        # Move only the current sublist bars up
        bars = arr[start:end]
        move_bars(bars, 5)
        update_location_all(bars, frame_num)
        frame_num += sort_speed

        # Recursively sort left and right halves
        merge_sort_animation(arr, start, mid, sort_speed)
        merge_sort_animation(arr, mid, end, sort_speed)

        # Merge the sorted halves
        merge_animation(arr, start, mid, end)

        # Move the merged bars back down
        move_bars(arr[start:end], -5)
        update_location_all(arr[start:end], frame_num)
        frame_num += sort_speed

def merge_animation(arr, start, mid, end):
    global sort_speed
    global frame_num
    left = arr[start:mid]
    right = arr[mid:end]
    i = j = 0
    sorted_bars = []
    # Get x-coordinates for the bars in this range
    coordinates = [bar.location.x for bar in arr[start:end]]

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i].scale.z <= right[j].scale.z:
            sorted_bars.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            sorted_bars.append(right[j])
            j += 1

    # Add any remaining bars
    sorted_bars.extend(left[i:])
    sorted_bars.extend(right[j:])

    # Update positions and keyframes
    for idx, bar in enumerate(sorted_bars):
        bar.location.x = coordinates[idx]
        update_location(bar, frame_num)

    # Update the original array with sorted bars
    arr[start:end] = sorted_bars
    frame_num += sort_speed

# Example usage
num_elements = 16           # Number of elements to sort
bar_width = 0.5             # Width of each bar
max_height = 20             # Max height for bars
sort_speed = 10             # Frames per action
frame_num = 1               # Start frame for the animation

# Clear existing objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

bars = create_bars(num_elements, bar_width, max_height)
update_location_all(bars, frame_num)
frame_num += sort_speed

merge_sort_animation(bars, 0, len(bars), sort_speed)

